# Magento 2 FedEx Shipment Package

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping-methods

Cannot create a package for FedEx shipment process. Please guide with the proper flow on how to create a package.

Comment: You can find details for configuring fedex, as well as creating packaging here: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-fedex-carrier-magento-2.html